# How do I find the column name corresponding to the maximum value in multiple rows and columns?

Tags: r

I can only find information for finding the max value for each row.
But I need the max value among multiple rows and columns and to find the column name corresponding to it.
e.g if my dataset looks like:

```
data <- data.frame(Year = c(2001, 2002, 2003),
                   X    = c(3, 2, 45),
                   Y    = c(6, 20, 23),
                   Z    = c(10, 4, 4))
```

I want my code to return "X" because 45 is the maximum.

Comment: If you are happy with one of the answers, please mark one of them as the accepted answer by clicking on the little checkmark symbol to the left.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one way to approach this is to turn your wide dataset into a long (tidy) table and then filter for the max value and extract that value name.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(text = "Year X Y Z
2001 3 6 10
2002 2 20 4
2003 45 23 4", header = T)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("X", "Y", "Z"), names_to = "column") %>% 
  filter(max(value) == value) %>% 
  pull(column)
# [1] "X"
```

And if you have a large number of columns, one method to "pivot" your data from wide to long without specifying all the columns names (as I do in the `pivot_longer(...)` command), you can run this instead:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = setdiff(names(.), "Year"), names_to = "column") %>% 
  filter(max(value) == value) %>% 
  pull(column)
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution:

Assuming that you want to exclude the `Year` variable from this analysis:

```
dat <- data.frame(Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002),
                  X    = c(1, 2, 45),
                  Y    = c(3, 4, 5))

dat_ex_year <- dat[, !names(dat) %in% c("Year")]
names(dat_ex_year)[which(dat_ex_year == max(dat_ex_year), arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]]
```

which gives:

```
[1] "X"
```

EDIT: I slightly adjusted the code so that it would return all column names in case the maximum value is found in several columns, e.g. with :

```
dat <- data.frame(Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002),
                  X    = c(1, 2, 45),
                  Y    = c(3, 45, 5))
```

the code gives:

```
[1] "X" "Y"
```